# Hermitian operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

When we say that an operator is Hermitian in QM, does it depend on the Hilbert space under consideration, or not? Are there operators that are Hermitian in one Hilbert space but not in another?

Comment: Have you illustrated this with finite-dimensional matrices and submatrices?

Comment: An operator is a map from one Hilbert space to another. It doesn't make sense to talk about it acting on a different Hilbert space surely?

Comment: Do we have to have a basis to answer that question?

Comment: @jacob1729 - let's go from $H$ to itself, so there is only one space.

Comment: @Frank yes, that's what I meant. I can't edit my comment anymore. My point stands that if you have any operator acting on some vector space, then there isn't a notion of it acting on some other vector space.

Comment: @jacob1729 - but here is the catch: a Hilbert space is an inner product space. I could take the same objects, but change the inner product, and I would get another Hilbert space "with the same objects" - that could happen for example when going from cartesian to polar coordinates "on the same space".

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase my question to mention "dependence on the inner product used to define the Hilbert space"?

Comment: @DanYand - that sounds like a good representation of what I'm trying to understand, and thanks for helping formulate the question, which is not always easy. I'll rephrase tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

There is a unique Hilbert space upto isomorphism for any given dimension.

So, a Hermetian operator on one Hilbert space of dimension $d$ is also a Hermetian operator on any other Hilbert space of the same dimension $d$.

So the answer to your question is no.